# SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user 'root'@'

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, mysql-5.1

Trying to root access our EC2 instance locally with Heidi, produces the error message, using external IP in client:

> SQL Error (1045) in statement #0: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'internal.host.net' (using password: YES)

Connecting with the internal IP, produces different error:

> SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '10.0.5.152' (10060)

The `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

No internal IP line, and no line of EC2 external hostname as:

> 10.0.5.152 hostname

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
```

> ```
> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*D0**********' WITH GRANT OPTION |
> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

```
user
root localhost
root ip-10-0-5-152
root 127.0.0.1
     localhost
     ip-10.0.5.152
```

Command I have executed is:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Tried from my machine, running Linux and MySQL Workbench, could connect EC2 IP.

Answer (score 1):

i faced similar problem, so for that i created new user by granting all the privileges and then i connected on ec2-instance and it was allowing me to connect after then, you can also do the same,

below are the steps.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'your_public_ip' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```